# Error Non static method cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: apex, unit-test

Test class:

```
 @isTest
 private with sharing class    Genereratortest {
 @TestSetup
 static void createPayloadtest() {
           List<_Site__c> studySites = new List<_Study_Site__c>{
            TestDataFactory.createStudySite('test','Data'),
        };
           
            Test.startTest();
            SSUDataJSONGenerator.createPayload(studySites,'INSERT');
            Test.stopTest();
    }
```

}
}

When I run this test class I am getting below error

```
Non static method cannot be referenced from a static context: String SSUDataJSONGenerator.createPayload(List<SObject>, String)
```

Not sure what’s the wrong with the test class.

Answer (score 1):

As written, you've made it so you have to construct an instance of your class:

```
        Test.startTest();
        SSUDataJSONGenerator generator = new SSUDataJSONGenerator();
        generator.createPayload(studySites,'INSERT');
        Test.stopTest();
```

If you didn't mean to add this complexity, change your method to static:

```
public static String createPayload(List<SObject> sobjrecords, String operation) {
```

You also need to use @isTest to denote a unit test method. @testSetup is only for creating test data (if necessary).

```
@isTest
 class SSUDataJSONGeneratorTest {
 @isTest
 static void createPayloadtest() {
           List<iqviaoctbase__Study_Site__c> studySites = new List<iqviaoctbase__Study_Site__c>{
            TestDataFactory.createStudySite('test','Data'),
        };
           
        Test.startTest();
        SSUDataJSONGenerator.createPayload(studySites,'INSERT');
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Frank You need to change `@TestSetup` to `@isTest`.

Comment: Ok can you please tell me what data should we give in test class to cover Payload part. From the below line code is not covering.                                                                                      String selection = getSelection(mappings );
    String query = 'SELECT ' +  selection  + ' FROM '
        + soName + ' WHERE id in :recordIDs';
           //  list<SObject>  records=Database.query(query );

Comment: @Frank I believe you forgot to `insert studySites;` before you called the method, so there was nothing to query.